# How to use the IVirtualDesktopManager interface in C++/Win32

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-10-desktop, virtual-desktop

I need to search for maximized windows from Win32 (by using `EnumWindows`) but I also want to filter for windows which are on the current virtual desktop. On MSDN, I found a page about the [`IVirtualDesktopManager` interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/mt186440%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) but there seems to be no information on how to use this interface.

```cpp
IVirtualDesktopManager::IsWindowOnCurrentVirtualDesktop(/*args...*/);
```

Throws the following error:

> Non static member reference must be relative to a specific object

```cpp
VirtualDesktopManager mVirtualDeskManager;
mVirtualDesktopManager.IsWindowOnCurrentVirtualDesktop(/args...*/)
```

Throws this error:

> Incomplete type is not allowed

I have only found solutions on using the `IVirtualDesktopManager` interface in C# yet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`IVirtualDesktopManager` is a COM interface.  You need to instantiate the COM object that implements the interface.

Based on code from [this blog](http://www.cyberforum.ru/blogs/105416/blog3671.html), you can use `IServiceProvider` to access `IVirtualDesktopManager` (and `IVirtualDesktopManagerInternal`, which has much more functionality than `IVirtualDesktopManager` has), eg:

```
IServiceProvider* pServiceProvider = NULL;
HRESULT hr = ::CoCreateInstance(
    CLSID_ImmersiveShell, NULL, CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER,
    __uuidof(IServiceProvider), (PVOID*)&pServiceProvider);

if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    IVirtualDesktopManager *pDesktopManager = NULL;
    hr = pServiceProvider->QueryService(__uuidof(IVirtualDesktopManager), &pDesktopManager);

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        BOOL bIsOnCurrentDesktop = FALSE;
        hr = pDesktopManager->IsWindowOnCurrentVirtualDesktop(hWnd, &bIsOnCurrentDesktop);

        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            // use bIsOnCurrentDesktop as needed...
        }

        pDesktopManager->Release();
    }

    pServiceProvider->Release();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and for the link. I've got a question regarding this, how did they manage to find how the interface looks like? I found IVirtualDesktopManagerInternals by going to the registry, so, I also found its GUID. However, I did not manage yet to find more information about the interface.

Comment: `IVirtualDesktopManager` is documented on MSDN. Other interfaces mentioned in that blog were likely determined through 3rd party sources, reverse engineering, etc.

Comment: Yeah sure, I was obviously talking about the other interfaces. It would be nice to have more information from the author about how he did it. Maybe I should just contact him.

Comment: Does this work (didn't tested)? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/cc678966%28v%3dvs.85%29 receives 3 args.

Comment: @CristiFati I honestly could not tell you, I've never used it myself. But I've seen examples that use both 2 and 3 parameter versions of `QueryService()`, such as [this one](https://github.com/Eun/MoveToDesktop/blob/master/Hook/hook.cpp)

Comment: Sorry, I started typing the comment, but somehow I browsed away from the page. It does work since the 2 arg form is a template overload that calls the 3 arg one. This is the equivalent: `hr = pServiceProvider->QueryService(__uuidof(IVirtualDesktopManager), __uuidof(IVirtualDesktopManager), (void**)(&pDesktopManager));` (strange, as the same *IID* is passed twice).